# Golang selectors - question about pointers spec sample

Tags: go

I'm reading the spec about selectors: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors

```
type T0 struct {
    x int
}

func (*T0) M0()

type T1 struct {
    y int
}

func (T1) M1()

type T2 struct {
    z int
    T1
    *T0
}

func (*T2) M2()

type Q *T2

var t T2     // with t.T0 != nil
var p *T2    // with p != nil and (*p).T0 != nil
```

I don't understand the comments of the last two lines.
At me t and p = nil

Comment: In the section of code that follows in the specification, assume that `t.T0 != nil`, `p != nil` and `(*p).T0 != nil`.

Comment: those are preconditions to the next paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The specs says:

> For example, given the declarations:
>
> [the code snippet you copied]
>
> one may write:
>
> [another code snippet with selector examples]

Consider `var t T2`. The struct `T2` embeds a pointer to `T0`. So the comment "*with t.T0 != nil*" means a variable `t` of type `T2` with a non-nil embedded `T0` field. Basically this:

```
var t = T2{
     T0: &T0{},
}
```

Then with such a variable, you can write the selector expression `t.x`, which equals `(*t.T0).x` showed in the subsequent code snippet. Since `x` is a field declared only in `T0`, the expression `t.x` amounts to dereferencing the embedded `t.T0`, which must be non-nil for that to be valid.

Same goes for `var p *T2`: the embedded `T0` must be non-nil, and `p` itself must be non-nil (it's a pointer). Basically this:

```
var p = &T2{
     T0: &T0{},
}
```

Then you can write the expression `p.x`, which amounts to dereferencing both `p` and the embedded `T0` field as shown in the comment `(*(*p).T0).x`